# API salesOrderInvoiceCreate throws: SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object has no 'invoiceIncrementId' property

Tags: api, invoice

I am doing a simple create invoice. I am getting this Fatal Error:

> Fatal error: SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object has no 'invoiceIncrementId' property

It shouldn't need an `invoiceIncrementId`, but it is throwing an error requiring one. I can't find anything online about this, not sure what is going on. Any ideas?

```
/** create invoice */
$magentoClient = MagentoClient::sharedClient();
$invoicecreate_request = $magentoClient->salesOrderInvoiceCreate( 
    (object)array(
        'sessionId' => $magentoClient->sessionId, 
        'orderIncrementId' => $order_id, 
        'itemsQty' => array(
            'order_item_id' => (string) $orderinfo_request->result->items->complexObjectArray->item_id, 
            'qty'           => (string) $orderinfo_request->result->items->complexObjectArray->qty_ordered
        ),
        'comment' => 'Created by Shopkeeper at '.date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
        'email' => null,
        'includeComment' => null
    )
);
```

The WSDL does indeed show it requires an `invoiceIncrementId`.

```
<xsd:element name="salesOrderInvoiceCreateRequestParam">
<xsd:complexType>
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="sessionId" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="invoiceIncrementId" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="itemsQty" type="typens:orderItemIdQtyArray"/>
<xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="comment" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="email" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="includeComment" type="xsd:string"/>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

Unfortunately, [the docs](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/sales/salesOrderInvoice/sales_order_invoice.create.html) do not.

```
$result = $proxy->salesOrderInvoiceCreate((object)array(
    'sessionId' => $sessionId->result, 
    'orderIncrementId' => '200000008', 
    'itemsQty' => array('order_item_id' => 15, 'qty' => '1'), 
    'comment' => null,
    'email' => null,
    'includeComment' => null
));
```

I must be misunderstanding something, but that's how this appears.

Answer (score 1):

If you look under `app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Invoice/Api/V2.php` for the function `create()` you will see that it indeed wants what is called a `invoiceIncrementId` but it really still wants a `orderIncrementId`.

See here the beginning of the code for the create function:

```
public function create($invoiceIncrementId, $itemsQty, $comment = null, $email = false, $includeComment = false)
{
    $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($invoiceIncrementId); 
    ...
```

This loads the order model with the normal order-increment number.

Compare this to the V1-Model under `app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Invoice/Api.php`:

```
public function create($orderIncrementId, $itemsQty, $comment = null, $email = false, $includeComment = false)
{
    $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderIncrementId);
    ...
```

So I just used this:

```
$result = $client->salesOrderInvoiceCreate((object)array(
    'sessionId' => $sessionId->result,
    'invoiceIncrementId' => '10052031',  // is called invoiceIncrementId, but actually it is orderIncrementId
    'itemsQty' => $itemsToInvoice,
    'comment' => null,
    'email' => null,
    'includeComment' => null
));
```

This created an invoice for my order number 10052031.